# Being asked to start teaching before being employed as a new faculty

Tags: united-states, immigration, academia

Suppose that a non-US person F is scheduled to join a US university as a teaching-focused faculty member. F's official starting is set to be January 4th and, at that university, classes start in the same week, and F will be teaching 2 courses in F's first term.

F has been inforems by HR hat F will need to apply for an SSN upon arrival in the US, and F will only be able to start working once F receives an SSN by mail, which may take 3-4 weeks. F's department head says this is normal, all foreign hires go through the same process. He also says F is  expected to start teaching F's courses right away, even if F isn't officially working yet.

1. Is this indeed the normal process/expectation for foreign hires? Also, is it even legal for the university to ask new hires to start working without putting them on the payroll?
2. Does F risk violating the terms of an H1B visa by "working" without being employed/paid?

Entering the US before the term starts to apply for the SSN number earlier isn't really an option, as F can only legally enter at most 10 days before the starting date of F's visa.

*(This was previously asked on academia.stackexchange, but it was suggested to cross-post this question here.)*

Comment: You nee a lawyer, not random stranger on the internet. If you think you can't afford one before doing anything, you definitely can't afford one after you do anything wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Worth reading [this document](https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10107.pdf) (pdf) from the US Social Security Administration (SSA). It describes the rules for **Foreign Workers and Social Security Numbers** and on the second page states:

> **Do I need to have my number before I  start working?**
>
> We don’t require you to have a Social Security  number before you start work.
> However, the Internal Revenue Service requires employers to use your Social
> Security number to report your wages.
>
> While you wait for your Social Security number, your employer can use
> a letter from us stating you applied for a number, and your
> immigration documents can prove your authorization to work in the
> United States.

Obviously, you should confirm this approach with your employer.